# eclipse + tomcat server site error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, resources

I use Eclipse Juno and tomcat server 7.0.39.

I created an Dynamic Web projet in eclipse and that worked fine. Project build and deploy on server and access to the url and worked fine.

But some times I get this instead of my app when i go to the same url of my app. (of course url is good and server on ;) )

[image: Tomcat fail]

I had to stop eclipse, re restart tomcat, had change NOTHING in code and now reworking fine

Any idea of the problem? it happend sometime and is very annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: No errors in log, sometimes i had to restart several times the server, sometimes eclipse, sometimes just wait, and this finaly works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still did'nt find why, but if I press CTRL+F5 one time it doesn't work again, but if if maintain CTRL+F5 down for a few seconds it reworks!

WTF?